# Is ANOVA appropriate for bounded-like data

Tags: regression, anova

my study has one variable with three groups and I'd like to examine the differences amongst these three groups.

The possible scores for the first group range from 0-18, while the possible scores for the other two groups range from 0-23. This seems like the data is 'bounded' (continuous?), however I was not sure if the comparison is valid, if the first group has a different possible maximum score from the two others. And if so, could I transform the data in any way to allow for a comparison?

Comment: How are the scores obtained? (what is this variable?) Why would an observed maximum of 18 imply that the score was bounded to be below 18?

Comment: @Glen_b Hi, the scores are from a test for 3 different classes, however in the first class, a 5-mark question was missing, thus the maximum score that someone could possibly get in that group was different from that of the other 2 groups

Comment: I don't see how you have a basis for comparison unless you can establish that the omitted questions are exactly as difficult and the questions that remained.  ... that aside, I believe your response is discrete (could one really get 13.961 ?), but it may be reasonable to treat it as if it were continuous. However, you usually shouldn't ignore the fact that these are bounded on both sides. In some cases - especially when hardly anyone is close to a boundary it may not matter much though. But at the very least you have to watch out for heteroskedasticity and skewness ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... (both are induced by boundary effects), and you should be wary of assuming shift alternatives on bounded variables.